# Mobclix won't turn on? (error code -9999999)

Tags: ios, iphone, service, dashboard, mobclix

I've set up Mobclix according to this guide (which is the same as Mobclix_SDK_iOS_61x_Guide.pdf in the [SDK zip file](http://downloads.mobclix.com/iphone/Mobclix%20SDK%206.1.3%20for%20iOS.zip))

https://developer.mobclix.com/help/advertising/quick

I've created an application ID, and added the following code to my AppDelegate class:

```
#define kMobclixAppID   @"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, MobclixAdViewDelegate>
//...
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Mobclix startWithApplicationId:kMobclixAppID];

    MobclixAdView   *adView = [[MobclixAdViewiPhone_320x50 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];

    adView.delegate = self;

    [((UINavigationController*) [self.window rootViewController]).view addSubview:adView];

    [adView resumeAdAutoRefresh];
    //[adView getAd];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MobclixAdViewDelegate

- (void)adView:(MobclixAdView*)adView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"Ad Failed: %@ %@.", NSStringFromCGSize(adView.frame.size), error);
}

@end
```

When I run my iOS app (both on the device and in the simulator), I get this error in the log:

```
Ad Failed: {320, 50} Error Domain=com.mobclix.ads Code=-9999999 "This ad unit size has been remotely disabled in the developer dashboard." UserInfo=0xa394560 {NSLocalizedDescription=This ad unit size has been remotely disabled in the developer dashboard.}.
```

Most of the ad services show the "disable" button instead of "pending" under Mobclix's [Services tab](https://developer.mobclix.com/services/advertising/networks) so I believe they are enabled.  I've gone into Setup and set:

```
Ads Running: Yes
Test Mode: Yes
```

But when I check the dashboard a few minutes later, "Ads Running" has reverted back to "No".  I'm at a loss as to why I can't turn on ads.  I've tried Test Mode: No and adding my UDID to [Developer Devices](https://developer.mobclix.com/account/general/developer).

My account is perhaps two hours old so I'm wondering if I have to wait a few days for ads to kick on?  But then what is the point of Test Mode?  Mobclix's ticket system is down so I can't request help.

P.S. I just saw that I can enable Email Notifications where I enter the UDID so I will try it and comment if it reveals the solution.  I'll go ahead and post this in case others are having trouble as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these guys are out of business...
http://finance.yahoo.com/news/mobclix-ceases-operations-files-voluntary-101300752.html

Comment: Ya I think so too, it sure would be nice if Mobclix, I don't know, maybe told us on their homepage instead of letting new users sign up :-/  I ended up going with AdMob and mixing the ads like this: http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_mixing_ads.php